# I'm writing pizza order program and I'm supposed to use enum for my crust class?

Tags: java, enums

I'm writing a pizza order program, which takes pizza orders.
This is my Crust class for my pizza program. We were told to use enum, but I've tried
this, but I don't think so it works.

`Crust.java:19: error: incompatible types
                return crust;
                       ^
  required: Crust
  found:    CrustType
Crust.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
                crust = CrustType.type;
                                 ^
  symbol:   variable type
  location: class CrustType
2 errors`

```
public class Crust
{   
    private enum CrustType {thin,hand,pan};
    //check crust type??
    private char size;`
    `//enum (crustType)`

    private CrustType crust;
    public Crust()
    {
    size = 'S';
        crust = CrustType.thin;
    }
    public char getSize()
    {
    return size;
    }
    //instead of enum
    public Crust getType()
    {
        return crust;
    }
    public void setSiz(char size)
    {
        this.size = size;
    }
    //This class sets the crust (enum) type what the user wants I'm not sure 
    //I'm not sure what type of should I pass to this method?
    public void setType(int type)
    {
        CrustType = type;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few issues.  First, if you want to use `CrustType` outside the class, you need to make it public:

```
public enum CrustType {thin,hand,pan};
```

Next, `getType` should return a `CrustType`:

```
public CrustType getType()
{
    return crust;
}
```

Lastly, `setType` should *take* a `CrustType` and set it to `crust`:

```
public void setType(CrustType type)
{
    crust = type;
}
```

Note: There's no sense in passing `setType` an `int`, that entirely defeats the purpose of using an `enum`.

Comment: Great Mike, I really appreciate it.

Comment: If you could, explain what is the purpose of using enum?
What is an enum?

Comment: You're basically defining a new data type (one that can represent a type of crust).  Using an `int`, your value could be anything; 5, 8, one billion.  Using an `enum`, you're guaranteed it *has to be* a valid crust type, so you don't need to check it and handle those errors.  Also, it makes your code prettier and easier to understand what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have two problems in your code:

1. `getType()` return type should be `CrustType`
2. `setType()` method should use instance variable `crust` to assign type, but you pass `int` parameter and I do not understand your intention there